# JavaFX - How to call a public void method from another controller when I close the other scene?

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

I have table view from the first fxml file which data's are from mysql db and with a method that loads the data to the table view, then on that fxml file I have a Registration button that open a new scene (Second FXML) where I can fill up if I want to add new profile. I was already able to insert the datas to the mysql database, the problem is when I close the form it doesnt show the latest data on the table view. What I want to happen, is when I close the scene (Second FXML), I want to call that method from the first fxml in order to re load the datas in the table view. Is there someone who can help?

Comment: Pass the table's `items` list to the second controller (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310#14190310) for how). Then in the second controller you can just add the new item to the list, and it will appear in the table.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro, ill check it out.